# Application don't works when pricipal activity inherits of ListActivity class

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a simple list application in Android 4.1 and when it's inheriting of `Activity`, works perfectly... but when this same application inherit of ListActivity, it fails.
Could anyone tell me why?

Comment: what's the problem you are facing ? could you post the logcat

Comment: See this lesson:
http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/notepad-ex1.html

Comment: Everything is fine until inherit from ListActivity in step 7

Comment: i am asking what's the error you are getting if any

Comment: so what's the code you used to make the listview

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(609): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lecheta.cap3.list/com.lecheta.cap3.list.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a listview in your layout xml file.Change it as below.

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
```

and check whether its working or not

check out the sample [here](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-list-view-sample.html). You may find this useful.
This is a sample where list view is obtained from extending the ListActivity.

also have a glance at this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`. To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id `"@android:id/list"`

Comment: I followed your tutorial, and again it all comes back to the beginning
I use ListActivity and does not work ... when I return to the Activity and make adjustments, works perfectly.

The listview already existed in xml.

Comment: Why does listview using the application break?

Comment: what's the id of the listview that you have?

Comment: with android:id="@android:id/list"
ListActivity Works... But why?